# What is the reason behind the concept of OOP in java that "Overriding variable is not allowed"?

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I know that all variables in any classes normally should be encapsulated, And another one could not be access but itself.

But in case of child class, I wonder that why child class can not access its variables that inherit from mother class (e.g. `Mother` class has variable `A = ""` and when you create `Child` class that `extends` from `Mother` class. you are not allowed to change variable `A` to another value (overriding) immediately in `Child` class).

And yes, there are another way to do this we can use `constructor` and `super` keyword to solve this problem. the question is that why they do not allow us to do it more simply way? for example just allow us to override variables that much much more easier that using `constructor` and `super` keyword. I think should have some reason to support this. Right?

Comment: If you did that, then you would be shadowing (or hiding) the field from the parent class. What would overriding that field look like and what behavior would you expect it to alter in the parent class (and why)? And if it doesn't alter the behavior of the parent class then it is just hiding the field. See also making the field(s) `private` then they aren't inherited at all.

Comment: You seem confused between private variables, which are dictated by the programmer, not the language, and overriding of variables, which isn't so much 'not allowed' as 'not possible', as you get hiding instead.

Comment: An instance of a subclass **can** directly access variables inherited from the superclass, provided that the access control level of the variable allows it.  A subclass instance can *modify* accessible variables inherited from the superclass if they are not `final`.  Whether allowed or not in any particular case, such modifications do not constitute "overriding" -- that's something altogether different.

Comment: Assuming the extending class has access to the fields of its parent class, they can be accessed using the form ChildClassName.super.fieldName. No need to involve a constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about protecting the internal implementations of the objects involved, and providing the author of the subclass with a contract that limits what the subclass needs to know about the superclass.

It should be up to the author of a class what the scope of its instance variables are, and the way that the author controls that scope is by assigning access modifiers to them or by passing references to them through method calls.

If the language allowed the subclasses to change any variables of any superclass then there would be too much potential for the subclass to break the superclass, and no way to change the superclass implementation details without risking breakage to the subclasses.